# Why do I have to remove a control from Controls and re-add it back for it to display again?

Tags: c#, winforms

Given the following code winform code:

```
   public partial class WebBrowserForm : Form
    {
        public WebBrowserForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Previewer.Show();
            this.webBrowser1.Refresh();
            Previewer.Navigate("http://google.com");
        }

        private WebBrowser Previewer
        {
            get
            {
                if(webBrowser1 == null || webBrowser1.IsDisposed)
                {
                    //Controls.Remove(webBrowser1); 

                    webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();

                    //Controls.Add(webBrowser1);

                    this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
                    this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
                    this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
                    this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(776, 250);
                    this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
                    this.webBrowser1.Show();                    
                }

                return webBrowser1;
            }
        }

        private void btnDispose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

If I click Load, then Dispose and then Load again the WebBrowser control does not reappear on the form.

If I remove it, new up a new one and re-add to the Controls, the WebBrowser control works as expected. (Uncomment the two lines below to get the example to work).

Why do I have to remove and re-add to Controls to get the example to work?

Comment: After Disposing it it is irretrievably dead. Why not simply Hide??

Comment: Here is the deal (not my design). The app uses the control to preview documents but there is a time when the document must be deleted. The control holds a reference to the document even after navigating away and the delete fails. The only way right now that I can find without rewriting a completely new solution to this is to dispose the control and recreate. So this way works for me but I am wondering why I have to re-add to the Controls to get to work instead of jus being able to replace the reference with a new one.

Comment: Probably because after `Dispose`, there are no more references to that location...

Comment: The variable I have is a reference though.

Comment: yes, you still have a reference but the instance is dead. do not dipose if you don't mean it. setting HtmlDocument = null should do, no? or webBrowser1 = new WerBroswer();

Comment: @RufusL so after some more tests it appears that calling Dispose actually removes the reference from the Controls collection even though I can still check most of the controls properties without issue (some give a disposed exception in the debuggeR).

Comment: Why do you even dispose it at all, why not just hide it, also when calling the control after disposing it, try using `webBrowser1.Refresh();`

Comment: @preciousbetine  The OP just explained why the control can't be hidden (at this time). Refreshing a Disposed control is something you should try.

Comment: _OP just explained why the control can't be hidden_ Hm I must have missed this.

Comment: @TaW Second comment down

Comment: Hm, makes no sense to me. Did you try my other suggestions?

Comment: @TaW  Disposing of a Control after its life-cycle has ended (for a reason or another) is normal procedure (as you well know) and avoids memory leaks (supposing that the Control disposes of its resources correctly). IMO, trying to re-set a reference to a `new()` one to avoid a `Control.Add()` isn't worth it (and possibly lethal :).

Comment: _after its life-cycle has ended_ Well this seems rather doubtful to me. Anyway, the question was _Why do I have to re-create_ and the answer is _because you have disposed of it_

Comment: @TaW  Yes, it seems strange that a WebBrowser controls needs to be disposed of after presenting a document (it's the IE engine after all - you don't usually close the Browser to reload a new document). It's not something common. I just have to believe that the OP has tested an alternative solution and didn't get the desired results. Why the Control needs to be re-added after it has been disposed of is obvious.

Comment: This is not my design but they are using the WebBrowser to preview pdf documents. Navigating away doesn't release the handle on the file for whatever reason. The only way I have found to get rid of the handle so that the file can be moved / deleted is to dispose of this nasty control. I am trying to avoid rewriting a completely new solution if possible. Removing and disposing and then renewing an object is not an uncommon thing and really has nothing to do with my actual question which is why does it disappear from the Controls collection when I re-new it up?

Comment: Well, this is the standard behaviour (and the desired one). When you want to remove a Control from a Controls collection (because you don't need it anymore or you have to rebuild the interface), you dispose of the Control. It will be removed from the collection right away. Then, of course, if you need a new instance: you create one and re-add it to the container, using `Controls.Add()`.

Comment: @Jimi That's what I was kind of looking for althgouh when I skimmed the source for Control.ControlsCollection nothing obvious stood out there for me I didn't spend a whole lot of time).

Comment: That was just a description of a (standard) WinForms behaviour. About the, probably, real issue: you could try to clear the WebBrowser cache creating a new HtmlDocument that doesn't preserve the browsing history. See the Docs about `WebBrowser.Document.OpenNew(true)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here (in the source code) for Component (virtual Dispose method implementation): https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/Component.cs,ec402748f4bd1220

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (disposing) {
        lock(this) {
            if (site != null && site.Container != null) {
                site.Container.Remove(this);
            }
            if (events != null) {
                EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)events[EventDisposed];
                if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you call dispose (unless overridden) it removes itself from its parent (container).

Comment: You probably wanted this reference [System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,5973). But, all in all, it's the same process.

Comment: Actually the code for Winforms is located in Component's virtual 
dispose.

Comment: Only when you get to `base.Dispose(disposing)`.

Comment: (I delete a part of the comment, as usual. Damn tablet :). Before, all Controls in the `ControlCollection` are disposed of, too. `this.Control` can be a Container, too. It's an interesing cascading effect.